# JS Subclass with default values

Tags: javascript, subclass

I have an `Atom` class (which represents an element's atom in the material universe):

```
class Atom {
    constructor(neutronCount) {
        this.neutronCount = neutronCount;
    }
}
```

There are 92 naturally occurring elements — one of these is Oxygen for example. I would like to create a subclass for each of these elements.

```
class Oxygen extends Atom {
    // By default, an oxygen atom has 8 neutrons but this can change.
    // How can I define the subclass in such a way that Oxygen has 
    // 8 neutrons by default?
}
```

An *normally-occurring* oxygen atom a default number of neutrons (8) but this can change, so I wish to be able to create an atom like this:

```
var o = new Oxygen(); // creates Oxygen with 8 neutrons
var o9 = new Oxygen(9); // create Oxygen with 9 neutrons
```

How can I define the Oxygen subclass in such a way that allows me to enter an optional parameter (number of neutrons)? And if I do not enter a param, it takes the default of `8`?

Comment: Just saying, making 92 subclasses doesn't sound like a good idea. Better just give the `Atom` class a `protonCount`, and make a lookup table between name of the element and the number of protons.

Comment: FWIW, I second @bergi's point above. Meant to say something earlier and...hey, look, something bright and shiny over there!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [*default parameter value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```
class Oxygen extends Atom {
    constructor(neutronCount = 8) {
    // ---------------------^^^^
        super(neutronCount);
    }
}
```

That's roughly the equivalent of:

```
class Oxygen extends Atom {
    constructor(neutronCount) {
        if (neutronCount === undefined) {
            neutronCount = 8;
        }
        super(neutronCount);
    }
}
```

so the `8` will be used in `new Oxygen()` and also in `new Oxygen(undefined)`.

If you like, you can even add some range checking before calling `super` if there's a reasonable range to apply. I don't know anything about molecular physics (or is it chemistry?), but for instance, if only the range 5 <= x < 10 is reasonable, then:

```
class Oxygen extends Atom {
    constructor(neutronCount = 8) {
        if (neutronCount < 5 || neutronCount >= 10) {
            throw new Error(`Oxygen cannot have a neutron count of ${neutronCount}`);
        }
        super(neutronCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to create atoms with any number of neutrons, however when they exceed a certain proton / neutron rate then they collapse. (So applying a limit might be reasonable for *relatively stable atoms*)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a Mixed in class:

```
 class Atom { }

  const AtomWithDefault = defaultNeutrons => class AtomWithDefault extends Atom {
    constructor(neutronCount = defaultNeutrons) {
       this.neutronCount = neutronCount;
    }
  };

  const Oxygen = AtomWithDefault(8);

  console.log(new Oxygen(9), new Oxygen);
```